# Writting on an file not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a problem that is:

I have a program that writes on a file throw File.WriteAllText, and it works fine until I close the activity in which it writes. When I close that activity, the file hasn't saved the changes I've made.

What might be the problem?

```
var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            var filename = Path.Combine(path, "Produtos.txt");
            atual = File.ReadAllText (filename);
            novo = atual + System.Environment.NewLine + _nome + ";" + _preco + ";" + _unidade + ";" + _categoria;
            File.WriteAllText (filename, novo);
```

Comment: post some code to get more information

Comment: Are you writing to a file that already exists? [Check it exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: yes, because I can read it

Comment: Then you want to append the text such as AppendAllText

Comment: it's the same thing right?